# Функция, которая сортирует по нескольким аргументам

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, инспекция-кода

Помогите пожалуйста с решением задачи:

Написать функцию `sort_gradebook(gradebook)`, принимающую на вход некую ведомость в виде списка, элементами которого являются списки такого вида:

`[first_name, last_name, grade_1, grade_2, ..., grade_n, final_grade]`,

где:

- `first_name` — имя студента,
- `last_name` — его фамилия,
- `grade_1, ..., grade_n` — оценки студента по контрольным от 1 до n (число n — общее число контрольных, оно одинаковое для конкретного `gradebook`, но заранее не известно),
- `final_grade` — итоговая оценка.

Функция должна отсортировать `gradebook` следующим образом (и вернуть его отсортированным):

- По итоговой оценке
- При совпадении итоговой оценки — по оценке за первую контрольную
- При совпадении всего предыдущего — по оценке за вторую контрольную
- При совпадении всего предыдущего — по оценке за третью контрольную (и т.д. пока контрольные не закончатся)
- При совпадении всех оценок — по фамилии
  *При совпадении всех оценок и фамилии — по имени

Примеры:

```
from itertools import permutations
def test_sort(inp, outp):
    for i in permutations(inp):
        assert sort_gradebook(list(i)) == outp
test_sort([
['Alice', 'Smith', 2, 3, 4],
['John', 'Smith', 2, 3, 5]   
], [   

    ['John', 'Smith', 2, 3, 5],
    ['Alice', 'Smith', 2, 3, 4]
])


test_sort([
    ['Alice', 'Smith', 2, 3, 4],
    ['John', 'Smith', 2, 3, 4]
], [
['Alice', 'Smith', 2, 3, 4],
['John', 'Smith', 2, 3, 4]
])
```

Вот, что я смог сделать:

```
def function(*examples):
    length = len([str(i) for i in examples[0]])
    a = [i for i in range(length)]
    for i in a:
        s = sorted(examples, key = itemgetter(i))
    return s
```

В какой бы последовательности я не сортировал (с 0 по 4, или с 4 по 0) - никак не получается соответствовать условиям задачи. Не знаю что делать.

Благодарю.

Comment: @CrazyElf Здравствуйте! Хочу попросить вашей помощи. Уже много дней не могу решить задачу. Был бы очень признателен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно отсортировать все списки по убыванию, тогда все просто:

```py
import operator


def sort_gradebook(gradebook):
    return sorted(
        gradebook, 
        key=operator.itemgetter(-1, slice(2, -1), 1, 0), 
        reverse=True
    )
```

здесь `-1, slice(2, -1), 1, 0`:

- последний элемент, итоговая оценка;
- срез для оценок, сколько бы их ни было;
- второй элемент, фамилия;
- первый элемент (с индексом 0), имя ученика

Но, если я правильно понял вопрос, задача усложняется тем, что оценки должны быть в порядке убывания (от высоких к низким), а фамилии и имена - по возрастанию, т.е. в алфавитном порядке?

В таком случае есть смысл в функции, принимающей как критерии сортировки, так и направление для каждого из них (вдруг, завтра изменят условие задачи):

```py
def sort_gradebook(gradebook, rev_descending):
    new_gradebook = gradebook.copy()

    for key, reverse in reversed(rev_descending):
        new_gradebook.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(key), reverse=reverse)

    return new_gradebook
```

где в качестве параметра `rev_descending` передается итерируемый объект (список, кортеж):

```
[[-1, True], [slice(2, -1), True], [1, False], [0, False]]
```

И, наконец, неплохо было бы проверить работоспособность:

```py
import operator
import unittest


def sort_gradebook(gradebook, rev_descending):
    new_gradebook = gradebook.copy()
    for key, reverse in reversed(rev_descending):
        new_gradebook.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(key), reverse=reverse)
    return new_gradebook


class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_sort_gradebook(self):
        self.assertEqual(sort_gradebook(
            [
                ['Alice',   'Smith',    2, 3,   4],
                ['John',    'Smith',    2, 3,   5]
            ],
            [[-1, True], [slice(2, -1), True], [1, False], [0, False]]
        ),
            [
                ['John',    'Smith',    2, 3,   5],
                ['Alice',   'Smith',    2, 3,   4]
            ]
        )

        self.assertEqual(sort_gradebook(
            [
                ['John',    'Smith',    2, 3,   4],
                ['Alice',   'Smith',    2, 3,   4],
            ],
            [[-1, True], [slice(2, -1), True], [1, False], [0, False]]
        ),
            [
                ['Alice',   'Smith',    2, 3,   4],
                ['John',    'Smith',    2, 3,   4]
            ]
        )

        self.assertEqual(sort_gradebook(
            [
                ['John',    'Smith',    4, 4, 5, 4, 4,  4],
                ['Alice',   'Smith',    4, 4, 5, 4, 4,  4],
                ['Lima',    'Navarro',  5, 4, 5, 4, 5,  4],
                ['John',    'Hopkins',  2, 3, 3, 4, 3,  3],
                ['Paolo',   'Maroni',   2, 1, 2, 3, 5,  3],
                ['Ali',     'Baba',     4, 5, 5, 5, 5,  5],
                ['Cun',     'Baba',     4, 5, 5, 5, 5,  5],
                ['Bar',     'Baba',     5, 5, 5, 5, 5,  5]
            ],
            [[-1, True], [slice(2, -1), True], [1, False], [0, False]]
        ),
            [
                ['Bar',     'Baba',     5, 5, 5, 5, 5,  5],
                ['Ali',     'Baba',     4, 5, 5, 5, 5,  5],
                ['Cun',     'Baba',     4, 5, 5, 5, 5,  5],
                ['Lima',    'Navarro',  5, 4, 5, 4, 5,  4],
                ['Alice',   'Smith',    4, 4, 5, 4, 4,  4],
                ['John',    'Smith',    4, 4, 5, 4, 4,  4],
                ['John',    'Hopkins',  2, 3, 3, 4, 3,  3],
                ['Paolo',   'Maroni',   2, 1, 2, 3, 5,  3]
            ]
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

После запуска файла в терминале $ python gradebook.py:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```